# DAC Bank Loan Automation

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, css-selectors

I'm a beginner. I'm trying to write JavaScript code to display the message "Thank you `<customerName>`. Your Loan Amount is `<loanAmount>` " in a div tag with id  'result' .

I tried this code:

```
<script>
        function display()
        {
            var name=document.getElementByName("customerName").value;
            var amount=document.getElementByName("loanAmount").value;
            
            
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Thank you" +name+ "Your loan amount is 
          +amount;
           
        }
    </script>
```

> I'm getting this error:
> Fail 1 - Check with the Javascript code or Check with Client UI requirements

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing Quotation mark. Also as the answer mentions, you aren't using [document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) correctly.

```js
  function display()
  {
      var name = document.getElementsByName("customerName")[0].value;
      var amount = document.getElementsByName("loanAmount")[0].value;
    
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Thank you" +name+ "Your loan amount is" +amount;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Syntax is  **document.getElementsByName**
For Value You Need to use

```
var name = document.getElementsByName('customerName')[0].value //For value
```

the Below code works

```js
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function()
            {
            var name = document.getElementsByName('customerName')[0].value
            var amount=document.getElementsByName('loanAmount')[0].value;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Thank you" +name+ "Your loan amount is " +amount;
            });
```

```html
Customer Name : <input type="text" name="customerName">

Loan Amount : <input type="number" name="loanAmount">
<input type="button" id="demo"  value="Click">
<p id="result"></p>
```